# How can I use python to download Minecraft server software?

Tags: python, download, minecraft

I am creating a python application that will download a Minecraft server JAR file and use it to automatically create and configure a Minecraft server. My goal is to have the software download a Minecraft server JAR to use, but I do not know how to download all versions of Minecraft server software (how to format a download URL to do so) and how to do that with Python. TLDR: I need to know how to specify in the URL which version of Minecraft software to download.

Comment: You can use the `requests` module to downloads files severed via HTTP. As for the old jars... Not really my area of expertise but have a look [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148683/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-minecraft-server-jar-for-minecraft)

Answer (score 0):

This will download and store the Minecraft 1.9 server in a Jar file though this link is subject to change, which means you may want to look into hosting the server binaries yourself to get a permanent URL that wont change as Mojang changes the Minecraft website.

`import requests`

```
URL = "https://piston-data.mojang.com/v1/objects/f69c284232d7c7580bd89a5a4931c3581eae1378/server.jar"
response = requests.get(URL)
with open("server.jar", "wb") as file:
  file.write(response.content)
```